# executable jar of an applet

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I have a java program in eclipse. This program is deployed and can be launched in a JApplet. I want to be able to launch the program within the Japplet on the webpage, but also to give the possibility to the user to download an executable jar en launch it ont their desktop.

In eclipse I have an xml file that give me the possibility to launch the applet within eclipse. Here is the xml launch file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.javaApplet">
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_PATHS">
<listEntry value="/FW/java/src/jeu/client/be/fw/jeu/client/WhistApplet.java"/>
</listAttribute>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_TYPES">
<listEntry value="1"/>
</listAttribute>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.ui.favoriteGroups">
<listEntry value="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchGroup.debug"/>
<listEntry value="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchGroup.run"/>
</listAttribute>
<intAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.APPLET_HEIGHT" value="200"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.APPLET_NAME" value=""/>
<mapAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.APPLET_PARAMETERS">
<mapEntry key="language" value="FRANCAIS"/>
<mapEntry key="serveur" value="www.fw.be"/>
</mapAttribute>
<intAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.APPLET_WIDTH" value="200"/>
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH">
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry containerPath=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER&quot; javaProject=&quot;fw&quot; path=&quot;1&quot; type=&quot;4&quot;/&gt;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry internalArchive=&quot;/Fw/build/jars/cartes150FR.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry id=&quot;org.eclipse.jdt.launching.classpathentry.defaultClasspath&quot;&gt;&#10;&lt;memento exportedEntriesOnly=&quot;false&quot; project=&quot;FW&quot;/&gt;&#10;&lt;/runtimeClasspathEntry&gt;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry internalArchive=&quot;/Fw/build/jars/carteBEFR.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry internalArchive=&quot;/Fw/build/jars/iconesFR.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#10;"/>
<listEntry value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; standalone=&quot;no&quot;?&gt;&#10;&lt;runtimeClasspathEntry internalArchive=&quot;/Fw/build/jars/iconesNL.jar&quot; path=&quot;3&quot; type=&quot;2&quot;/&gt;&#10;"/>
</listAttribute>
<booleanAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.DEFAULT_CLASSPATH" value="false"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.MAIN_TYPE" value="be.fw.jeu.client.WhistApplet"/>
<stringAttribute key="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.PROJECT_ATTR" value="FW"/>
</launchConfiguration>
```

Now I want to know how can I make an executable jar or something else to be able to launch the program, without using the browser. I don't want them to download eclipse and import the entire code and the xml file to be able to launch the JApplet without browser.

Comment: Basically I see two options: build a jnlp file to download as "web-start", which runs without browser (Advantage: no code change) or add a real main class and put that into the Manifest which will make it a real stand-alone executable jar.

Comment: How do I build a jnlp file without changing something on my code. I thought you have to make an executable jar of my code to be able to use a jnlp file

Comment: Not necessarily, you can use web start to start an "Applet" w/o main, just like a jar used for an applet today... I suggest you start reading about that